# OOP Design Question - Linking to precursors

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

I'm writing a program to do a search and export the output.
I have three primary objects:

- Request
- SearchResults
- ExportOutput

Each of these objects links to its precursor.

**Ie:** ExportOutput -> SearchResults -> Request

Is this ok?  Should they somehow be more loosely coupled?

Clarification:

Processes later on do use properties and methods on the precursor objects.

**Ie:**

```
SendEmail(output.SearchResults.Request.UserEmail, BODY, SUBJECT);
```

This has a smell even to me. The only way I can think to fix it is have hiding properties in each one, that way I'm only accessing one level

```
MailAddress UserEmail
{
  get { return SearchResults.UserEmail; }
}
```

which would yeild

```
SendEmail(output.UserEmail, BODY, SUBJECT);
```

But again, that's just hiding the problem.
I could copy everything out of the precursor objects into their successors, but that would make ExportOutput really ugly.  Is their a better way to factor these objects.

**Note:** SearchResults implements IDisposable because it links to unmanaged resources (temp files), so I really don't want to just duplicate that in ExportOutput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A uses B directly, you cannot:

- Reuse A without also reusing B
- Test A in isolation from B
- Change B without risking breaking A

If instead you designed/programmed to interfaces, you could:

- Reuse A without also reusing B - you just need to provide something that implements the same interface as B
- Test A in isolation from B - you just need to substitute a Mock Object.
- Change B without risking breaking A - because A depends on an interface - not on B

So, at a minimum, I recommend extracting interfaces. Also, this might be a good read for you: the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf) (PDF file).

Comment: "Test A in isolation from B" - this isn't true, you just need to use a mocking framework that lets you mock any kind of class. The fact that many cannot do that is a deficiency in them. OO design should not have to be constrained or bent just because of test framework limitations - just find a better framework!

Comment: Also, "change B without risking breaking A" will be the same with and without extracted interfaces - adding new members isn't a breaking change for direct class access, and removing would be a breaking change even with an interface.

Comment: @Pavel: regarding "change B without risking breaking A", if A is intimately tied to B, and you make an implementation change to B, it is possible to introduce a bug to A (from the point of view of a user of A).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your specifics, I would think that results in whatever form would simply be returned from a Request's method (might be more than one such method from a configured Request, like find_first_instance vs. find_all_instances).  Then, an Exporter's output method(s) would take results as input.  So, I am not envisioning the need to link the objects at all.